# How to do the probability symbol in xlab with the package latex2exp?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, latex

I have tried to do the probability symbol in xlab of ggplot such as
:

```
library(latex2exp)

p + scale_x_continuous(name = TeX('$P(x_{i2})$'), breaks = seq(0,1,0.25),limits = c(0,1), labels = c('0','0.25','0.5','0.75','1'))
```

but it doesn't work if I do \mathbb{P} like I do in LaTeX...

Do you know how to do it ?

Huge thanks

Adrien

Comment: not everyone here is a mathematician, neither am I - not sure what exactly you have in mind with "probability symbol" - would you care elaborating?  Would you also care creating a dummy plot instead of just using "p"?

Comment: Hello. It is a like a bold P : https://www.google.com/search?q=mathbb%7BP%7D&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwio8ZiVlbjzAhWVq6QKHb0SDH0Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=mathbb%7BP%7D&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoHCCMQ7wMQJzoICAAQgAQQsQM6BQgAEIAEOggIABCxAxCDAToECAAQQzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6BwgAELEDEEM6BAgAEB46BAgAEBhQ0rADWJ7CA2CyxANoAHAAeACAAbQBiAHZBpIBAzcuMpgBAKABAaoBC2d3cy13aXotaW1nwAEB&sclient=img&ei=2tVeYaicIpXXkgW9pbDoBw&rlz=1C1CHBF_frFR836FR836#imgrc=Ghdfe9fN6vp5WM

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the unicode, '\u2119' for probability P ? It could work without having to call TeX function.